# JavaScript object property assignment

Tags: javascript, performance, javascript-objects

On this page -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript

" Once created, an object's properties can again be accessed in one of two ways:

```
obj.name = "Simon";
var name = obj.name;

obj["name"] = "Simon";
var name = obj["name"];
```

These are also semantically equivalent. **The second method has the advantage that the name of the property is provided as a string, which means it can be calculated at run-time though using this method prevents some JavaScript engine and minifier optimizations being applied**."

(**IN BOLD**) Why is the second method better? What are the JavaScript and minifier optimizations referred to here?

Please let me know if you need more information

Comment: The second method may **prevent** some JavaScript engine and minifier optimizations being applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second is not so much 'better' but safer, as it allows for properties with unconventional characters. For example:

```
obj.my-property = true; //parse errror
obj['my-property'] = true; //fine, because property name specified as string
```

It also allows you to build dynamic property names, e.g.

```
var prop_name = 'foo';
prop_name += 'bar';
obj[prop_name] = true;
```

The optimisation/minification point has to do with the fact that most if not all minifiers will leave strings strictly untouched, for reasons that are fairly obvious. Say you had:

```
var str = "hello";
```

Even if you minified your script, you would want your string to stay as "hello".

So a minification engine may turn

```
obj.foobar = true;
```

into

```
a.b=true;
```

But it wouldn't change

```
obj['foobar'] = true;
```

into

```
a['b']=true;
```

Comment: How is minimization equivalent to optimization here? Is it just optimizing the property name? Does that help performance?

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with minification, look into it. It is one of several forms of optimisation - not in the code refactoring sense, but in the reduction of code and reusing (redeclaration) of property names. Yes, minification normally helps performance.

Answer (score 1):

The second method allows you to dynamically construct the name at runtime:

```
// something passed in to the context
var name = firstName + "_name";

obj[name] = "some value";
```

This also supports characters (like hyphen `-`) that are not supported in JavaScript code:

```
obj["some-value"] = "some value";
```

And since string literals will not be touched by minification tools, `"name"` will not be minified, but `name` might be:

```
obj.name = "value";
obj.name = "another value":

// after minification:
obj.n = "value";
obj.n = "another value";
```

Whereas this will not be touched:

```
obj["name"] = "value";
obj["name"] = "another value";
```

Comment: Why would javascript rename the property name to n? What if I wanted to name a property n? Does it make coding easier? Easier to remember the property name?

Comment: JavaScript would not, but minification tools would.  Minification tools attempt to reduce the character count of JavaScript code.  They do this by renaming referenced variables to a small unique value.

Comment: Minification tools are not included in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

It's not better, it's just more flexible. Consider this:

```
var objects = [
  {
    x: 2,
    y: 3
  },
  {
    x: 32,
    y: 64
  },
  ...
];

var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0, len = objects.length; i < len; i++) {
  var property;
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    property = 'x';
  } else {
    property = 'y';
  }
  sum += objects[i][property];
}
```

This allows you to figure out, at run time, what property to access. The optimizations that this prevents are renaming the property to make the file smaller and, because the value is dynamic, the compiler can't predict ahead of time where it's going to pull the value from.

Answer (score 1):

The first method can be thought of 'syntactic sugar' for the second method.

While the first is more readable, and less typing, the second method gives you the ability to dynamically name the property.

An example of when you may find this useful, would be when trying to avoid ridiculously long switch-cases (if, if-else, if-else, else, etc).

You can avoid this using a hash map, like so:

```
function getFav(name) {
  var favoriteColors = {
    "bob": "red",
    "jim": "blue",
    "ana": "red",
    "sue": "purple"
  };
  // Here we use the second accessor method,
  // if 'name' is not inside the favoriteColors, we short-circuit to 'unknown'
  return favoriteColors[name] || "unknown"; 
}

getFav("bob"); // "red"
getFav("ana"); // "red"
getFav("sue"); // "purple"
getFav("dan"); // "unknown"
```

Answer (score 0):

The second method allows for names that would generally throw an error:

```
var obj = {}

//setting
obj.hyphenated-name = 'foo' //throws error
obj['hyphenated-name'] = 'foo' //works

//getting
obj.hyphenated-name //NaN or Undefined depending on your environment
obj['hyphenated-name']  //'foo'
```